# Assign sampled multinomial values uniformly at random

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, random

I am using `np.random.multinomial` to sample a multinomial distribution `M` times (given probabilities `[X_0 X_1 .. X_n]` it returns counts `[C_0 C_1 ... C_n]` sampled from the specified multinomial, where `\sum_i C_i = M`). Given these sampled values (the `C_i`'s), I want to assign them uniformly at random to some objects I have.

Currently what I'm doing is:

```
draws = np.random.multinomial(M, probs, size=1)
draws = draws[0]
draws_list = []
for idx,num in enumerate(draws):
    draws_list += [idx]*num
random.shuffle(draws_list)
```

Then `draws_list` is a randomly shuffled list of the sampled values.

The problem is that populating `draws_list` (the for loop) is very slow. Is there a better/faster way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. This strategy is to allocate the memory first, then to fill data.

```
draws_list1 = np.empty(M, dtype=np.int)
acc = 0
for idx, num in enumerate(draws):
    draws_list1[acc:acc+num].fill(idx)
    acc += num
```

Here's the full code for profiling.

```
import numpy as np
import cProfile

M=10000000

draws = np.random.multinomial(M, [1/6.]*6, size=1)
draws = draws[0]

draws_list1 = np.empty(M, dtype=np.int)

def impl0():
    draws_list0 = []
    for idx, num in enumerate(draws):
        draws_list0 += [idx]*num
    return draws_list0

def impl1():
    acc = 0
    for idx, num in enumerate(draws):
        draws_list1[acc:acc+num].fill(idx)
        acc += num
    return draws_list1

cProfile.run("impl0()")
cProfile.run("impl1()")
```

Here's the result of `cProfile`. If the statement `np.empty` is located in function `impl1`,  `0.020 seconds` are elapsed.

```
     3 function calls in 0.095 seconds

 Ordered by: standard name

 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      1    0.020    0.020    0.095    0.095 <string>:1(<module>)
      1    0.076    0.076    0.076    0.076 prof.py:11(impl0)
      1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}


       9 function calls in 0.017 seconds

 Ordered by: standard name

 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      1    0.000    0.000    0.017    0.017 <string>:1(<module>)
      1    0.000    0.000    0.017    0.017 prof.py:17(impl1)
      1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
      6    0.017    0.003    0.017    0.003 {method 'fill' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
```